# SQL - How to duplicate rows but change only one column info?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, cross-apply

The tblWeeks table has column weeknum and date (every Thursday only)
Like this:

```
WeekNum    Date
1496       2015-7-2
1497       2015-7-9
1498       2015-7-16
```

The fnBenchmarkData function will return weekly data based on specified weeknum parameter.

I used cross-apply to display the benchmark data for ALL weeks:

```
SELECT p.weeknum, p.date, q.Key, q.ID, q.Score      
FROM tblWeeks AS p 
cross apply 
fnBenchmarkData(p.weeknum) as q
```

Now my problem is, the score data generate from function and weeknum will update on every Thursday and remain the same till next Wednesday, i.e., **Thursday - next Wednesday is a "loop" and all score data are the same, weeknum is same too. However, the function will return Thursday only.**

The cross-apply will only display every Thursday data, I want to display the rest of the weekdays, basically duplicate the rows but change the date.

For example, below is what I get from cross-apply:

```
WeekNum    Date              Score
1496       2015-7-2 (Thur)     1
1497       2015-7-9 (Thur)     5   
1498       2015-7-16(Thur)     7
....
```

I want my cross-apply SQL return something like this:

```
WeekNum    Date              Score
1496       2015-7-2 (Thur)     1
1496       2015-7-3            1
                                     /* No data stored for weekend 
1496       2015-7-6            1   
1496       2015-7-7            1   
1496       2015-7-8            1

1497       2015-7-9 (Thur)     5
1497       2015-7-10           5

1497       2015-7-13           5   
1497       2015-7-14           5
1497       2015-7-15           5

1498       2015-7-16(Thur)     7
```

Anyone who have idea how to do that? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `cross join` to bring in the additional rows

```
SELECT p.weeknum, dateadd(day, n.n, p.date) as date, q.Key, q.ID, q.Score      
FROM tblWeeks p cross apply 
     fnBenchmarkData(p.weeknum) q cross join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
     ) n;
```

Comment: Instead of the many unions you could use `cross join (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) n(n);`

Comment: @Shnugo but that will require at least `SQL Server 2008` won't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below SQL script, tried to relate with requirement.. plz update script according to your need

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnBenchmarkData(@WeekNum INT,@BDate  DATETIME,@Score INT)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    WeekNum INT,
    BDate DATETIME,
    Score DATETIME
) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- NO DATA For Weekend
    IF(DatePart(WEEKDAY,@BDate) <> 1 AND DatePart(WEEKDAY,@BDate) <> 7)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue VALUES(@WeekNum,@BDate,@Score)
        -- Repeat For Thursday
        IF(DatePart(WEEKDAY,@BDate)) =5 --Thu repeat row
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @RtnValue VALUES(@WeekNum,@BDate,@Score)
        END
    END 
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Evaluate Function output using script

```
Select * From dbo.fnBenchmarkData(1496,'2015-07-09',1)
Select * From dbo.fnBenchmarkData(1496,'2015-07-08',1)
Select * From dbo.fnBenchmarkData(1496,'2015-07-11',1)
```

Now as you suggested in your query, use cross apply and pass expected parameter and use function output in select command.